# Analyzing Python 3 Stack Trace Requests Module requests.exceptions.SSLError: urllib3.exceptions.MaxRetryError: Max retries exceeded with url:

Tags: python-3.x, python-requests

Hello this is my first question on Stack Overflow...

I have written Python script which uses latest Python 3.7 and latest requests module.
My request queries work, however after multiple (thousands) of requests in a day, I sometimes get this stack trace and program exits. It is large stack trace and I am not sure which pieces I should investigate first. Any help would be greatly appreciated

**Here is the stack trace:**

```
File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/urllib3/contrib/pyopenssl.py", line 453, in wrap_socket
    cnx.do_handshake()
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/OpenSSL/SSL.py", line 1915, in do_handshake
    self._raise_ssl_error(self._ssl, result)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/OpenSSL/SSL.py", line 1639, in _raise_ssl_error
    raise SysCallError(errno, errorcode.get(errno))
OpenSSL.SSL.SysCallError: (104, 'ECONNRESET')

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 600, in urlopen
    chunked=chunked)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 343, in _make_request
    self._validate_conn(conn)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 841, in _validate_conn
    conn.connect()
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/urllib3/connection.py", line 344, in connect
    ssl_context=context)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/urllib3/util/ssl_.py", line 344, in ssl_wrap_socket
    return context.wrap_socket(sock, server_hostname=server_hostname)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/urllib3/contrib/pyopenssl.py", line 459, in wrap_socket
    raise ssl.SSLError('bad handshake: %r' % e)
ssl.SSLError: ("bad handshake: SysCallError(104, 'ECONNRESET')",)

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/requests/adapters.py", line 449, in send
    timeout=timeout
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 638, in urlopen
    _stacktrace=sys.exc_info()[2])
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/urllib3/util/retry.py", line 398, in increment
    raise MaxRetryError(_pool, url, error or ResponseError(cause))
urllib3.exceptions.MaxRetryError: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='block.io', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: /api/v2/get_address_balance/?api_key=0d76-078a-c2c9-e524&addresses=172MQBZyt2UGfCPRwUpKCH4cmB4sRrhywy (Caused by SSLError(SSLError("bad handshake: SysCallError(104, 'ECONNRESET')")))

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "Birds.py", line 291, in <module>
    main()
  File "Birds.py", line 287, in main
    loop()
  File "Birds.py", line 260, in loop
    checkBTC()
  File "Birds.py", line 186, in checkBTC
    currentBTCBalance = getBitcoinBalance()                              # Check Snapy for BTC balance
  File "Birds.py", line 111, in getBitcoinBalance
    r = requests.get(query_url)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/requests/api.py", line 75, in get
    return request('get', url, params=params, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/requests/api.py", line 60, in request
    return session.request(method=method, url=url, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/requests/sessions.py", line 533, in request
    resp = self.send(prep, **send_kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/requests/sessions.py", line 646, in send
    r = adapter.send(request, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/requests/adapters.py", line 514, in send
    raise SSLError(e, request=request)
requests.exceptions.SSLError: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='block.io', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: /api/v2/get_address_balance/?api_key=0d76-078a-c2c9-e524&addresses=172MQBZyt2UGfCPRwUpKCH4cmB4sRrhywy (Caused by SSLError(SSLError("bad handshake: SysCallError(104, 'ECONNRESET')")))
```

Answer (score 0):

I have answered my own question via these websites:
 https://www.peterbe.com/plog/best-practice-with-retries-with-requests
https://realpython.com/python-requests/

Which explain how to use Transport Adapters and smart backoff. I am currently testing queries once per second and the program has been running for 24 hours without problem.